# Get sum of followers from Twitter for 10,000 users

Tags: python, json, twitter

I am trying to get the number of followers of each twitter user for a list of 10,000 users randomly selected via a random number generator. I am using the GET users/lookup API by Twitter to do this. I can't use the GET followers directly due to the limit of 15 requests/ 15 mins. I managed to do this but my data is not in json format and I've spent the entire day trying to get jq to process it (which fails due to special character within the envelope). Can anyone suggest how do I do this?

I had no issues doing the same with Twitter's streaming API as the data was JSON format which was parse-able by jq. I need to do this with jq, python & shell scripting.

MY CODE TO GET THIS RESPONSE: (Python)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import json
import oauth2 as oauth
from random import randint
import sys
import time

ckey= '<insert-key>'
csecret= '<insert-key>'
atoken= '<insert-key>'
asecret= '<insert-key>'

consumer = oauth.Consumer(key= ckey, secret = csecret)
access_token = oauth.Token(key=atoken, secret=asecret)
client= oauth.Client(consumer, access_token)

# Print to a file
sys.stdout = open('TwitterREST.txt', 'w')

for j in range(0,20):
    for i in range(0, 900):
        user_id =(randint(2361391150, 2361416150))

        f="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?user_id="
        s=str(user_id)
        timeline_endpoint = f+s

        response,data=client.request(timeline_endpoint)
        tweets= json.loads(data)

        for tweet in tweets:
            print (data)

    # Twitter only allows 900 requests/15 mins
    time.sleep(900)
```

*SAMPLE RESPONSE RETURNED BY TWITTER:* (Cannot pretty print it)

b'[  {  "id":2361393867,  "id_str":"2361393867",  "name":"graam a7bab",  "screen_name":"bedoo691",  "location":"",  "description":"\u0627\u0633\u062a\u063a\u0641\u0631\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647 \u0648\u0627\u062a\u0648\u0628 \u0627\u0644\u064a\u0647\u0647 ..!*",  "url":null,  "entities":   {   "description":    {    "urls":[]}    },    "protected":false,    "followers_count":1,    "friends_count":6,    "listed_count":0,    "created_at":"Sun Feb 23 19:03:21 +0000 2014",    "favourites_count":1,    "utc_offset":null,    "time_zone":null,    "geo_enabled":false,    "verified":false,    "statuses_count":7,    "lang":"ar",    "status":     {      "created_at":"Tue Mar 04 16:07:44 +0000 2014",      "id":440881284383256576,      "id_str":"440881284383256576",      "text":"@Naif8989",      "truncated":false,      "entities":{       "hashtags":[],       "symbols":[],       "user_mentions":[       {        "screen_name":"Naif8989",        "name":"\u200f  naif alharbi",        "id":540343286,        "id_str":"540343286",        "indices":[0,9]}],        "urls":[]},        "source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/android\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for Android\u003c\/a\u003e",        "in_reply_to_status_id":437675858485321728,        "in_reply_to_status_id_str":"437675858485321728",        "in_reply_to_user_id":2361393867,        "in_reply_to_user_id_str":"2361393867",        "in_reply_to_screen_name":"bedoo691",        "geo":null,        "coordinates":null,        "place":null,        "contributors":null,        "is_quote_status":false,        "retweet_count":0,        "favorite_count":0,        "favorited":false,        "retweeted":false,        lang":"und"},        contributors_enabled":false,        is_translator":false,        is_translation_enabled":false,        profile_background_color":"C0DEED",        profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png",        profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png",        profile_background_tile":false,        profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/437664693373911040\/ydODsIeh_normal.jpeg",        profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/437664693373911040\/ydODsIeh_normal.jpeg",        profile_link_color":"1DA1F2",        profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED",        profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6",        profile_text_color":"333333",        profile_use_background_image":true,        has_extended_profile":false,        default_profile":true,        default_profile_image":false,        following":false,        follow_request_sent":false,        "notifications":false,        "translator_type":"none"       }      ]'

Comment: please make it readable

Comment: Perhaps you could use the [python-twitter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-twitter/3.3) module from PyPi? There are more libraries listed on [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/resources/twitter-libraries). If you showed your code, folks might be able to assist.

Comment: @ SACn Sorry tried pretty printing the output, but failed.

Comment: Added Python code used to get the data